# Getting Error while running maven automation suite from Jenkins server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I am setting jenkin job to run my Maven Automation test-suite.When I am doing build with Goal "test" then I am getting below Error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BBAPI-Automation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ BBAPI-Automation ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BB-APIAutomation/workspace/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ BBAPI-Automation ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BB-APIAutomation/workspace/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ BBAPI-Automation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 18 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BB-APIAutomation/workspace/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BB-APIAutomation/workspace/src/main/java/com/bb/mapi/cities/Cities.java:[7,22] package io.restassured does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BB-APIAutomation/workspace/src/main/java/com/bb/mapi/cities/Cities.java:[8,27] package io.restassured.http does not exist
```

Below is my pom.xml file. It is running from eclipse but getting error while running the suite from jenkin server.
It seems jenkins is unable to download dependencies. I am not sure about the issue

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bigbasket</groupId>
  <artifactId>BBAPI-Automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>BBAPI-Automation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${testng}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <printSummary>true</printSummary>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

 </build>


  <properties>  
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>  

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
         <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.48</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add io.rest-assured to dependecies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you show your Cities.java, and imports you have mentioned there.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: public class Cities extends CitySuiteConfig {
  
 @Test(groups = {"prod", "sanity"},priority=2)
 public void BBS_789_getCityList() throws IOException {
  
  
  RestAssured.baseURI = System.getProperty("server_url");
  
  Response cityResponse = given().
  when().
  get(CitiesResourceClass.cityResource()).
  then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).
  extract().response();
  
  System.out.println(cityResponse.asString());
  Reports.reporter("City List", true);
  
  
  
 }

}

Comment: Have you checked manually whether jar rest-assured is downloaded while compiling and executing the code??

Comment: Sorry in jenkins , jar files have not downloaded

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: any clue?

Comment: while building the job, check the work space of the job and there you can find whether maven tries to download or is there any issue with the jars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150727/discussion-between-saurabh-garg-and-chandra-sekhar).